# Ant build - Java project - exception at runtime with .properties

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit, jenkins

I have this exception at runtime, while starting my test(junit) campaign from Jenkins, using ant tool: ***java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name*** com.mainpackage.V_45_4_3.view.translation.Translation, locale en_US

The Translation_en_US.properties exists in that directory and it looks like it's a path/classpath problem.

This happens only when I use ant build tool. From Eclipse everything is working fine.
I'll paste the .xml file used by ant:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<!--  -->

<property name="root.dir" location="." />
<property name="src.dir" location="${root.dir}/src" />
<property name="bin.dir" location="${root.dir}/bin" />
<property name="lib.dir" location="${root.dir}/lib" />

<property name="local.tests.dir" location="C:/NEMTESTS" />

<property name="test.src.dir" location="${root.dir}/tests" />

<property name="test.bin.dir" location="${local.tests.dir}/bin" />




<property name="javaClasspath" value="
            ${root.dir};
            ${bin.dir};
            ${lib.dir}/AdventNetSnmp.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/AdventNetLogging.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/ranabFtp.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/castor-1.2.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/synthetica.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/alu_LAF.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/jbasiccomp_java2.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/jnavapi_java2.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/jsch-0.1.50.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/j2ssh-daemon-0.3.1.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/j2ssh-core-0.3.1.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/j2ssh-common-0.3.1.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/j2ssh-core-0.2.9.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/commons-io-1.4.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/tar.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/maverick-debug-all.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/maverick-sshd-debug-no-j2ssh.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/fest-assert-1.3.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/fest-reflect-1.2.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/fest-swing-1.2.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/fest-util-1.1.4.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/fest-swing-junit-1.2.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/fest-swing-junit-4.5-1.2.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/jcip-annotations-1.0.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/junit-4.8.2.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/pmd-4.2.5.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/asm-3.1.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/jaxen-1.1.1
            ${lib.dir}/log4j-java1.1.jar;
            ${lib.dir}/commons-logging-1.1.jar" />

<target name="test" depends="prepare, test-compile, run-tests, finish-errors, finish" />

<target name="prepare"> 

    <delete dir="${test.bin.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${test.bin.dir}" />

</target>


<target name="test-compile" description="Compile Java tests">

    <javac destdir="${bin.dir}" debug="false" optimize="yes" fork="yes" includeantruntime="false" >
        <src refid="test-src-path" />
        <classpath>
            <path refid="test-lib-path" />
            <path refid="run-classpath" />
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="run-tests" description="Run GUI tests">
    <junit fork="no"  haltonfailure="no" haltonerror="no" errorproperty="test.failed" failureproperty="test.failed" printsummary="no" showoutput="yes">
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx1024m" />


        <classpath>
            <path refid="test-lib-path" />
            <path refid="run-classpath" />
        </classpath>

        <formatter classname="nem.utils.OneLinerFormatter" usefile="false" />
        <formatter type="xml" />

        <test name="nem.AllTests" todir="${test.bin.dir}" />
    </junit>

    <junitreport todir="${local.tests.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${local.tests.dir}" >
            <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report todir="${local.tests.dir}" format="frames"/>
    </junitreport>
</target>


<target name="finish-errors" if="test.failed">
    <echo>GUI tests failed.  Check logs in workspace for details</echo>
</target>

<target name="finish" unless="test.failed"> 
    <echo>NEM is ok. Is it ...?</echo>
</target>

<path id="run-classpath">
    <pathelement location="${bin.dir}" />
    <path refid="test-lib-path" />
</path>

<path id="test-src-path">
    <pathelement location="${test.src.dir}" />
</path>

<path id="test-lib-path">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<path id="test-run-classpath">
    <pathelement location="${test.bin.dir}" />
    <path refid="test-lib-path" />
</path>
```

EDIT:

Well, when I say everything works fine from Eclipse I'm saying that tests start and run as they should by using JUnit (Eclipse integrated).

The error also appears when running the ant -f .xml from command line. It's the same thing.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
prepare:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\NEMTESTS\bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\NEMTESTS\bin

test-compile:

run-tests:
    [junit] 
    [junit] ----------------------------------------------------------
    [junit] Testsuite: nem.AllTests
    [junit] java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name mainpackage.rlr14_01.V_45_4_3.view.translation.Translation, locale en_US
    [junit]     at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
    [junit]     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
    [junit]     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:795)
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.view.translator.Translator.createTranslation(Translator.java:125)
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.view.translator.Translator.<init>(Translator.java:31)
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.view.translator.TranslatorFactory.getTranslator(TranslatorFactory.java:116)
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.manager.BsManager.setMibVersion(BsManager.java:1469)
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.action.ConnectAction.action(ConnectAction.java:314)
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.action.AbstractAction.run(AbstractAction.java:164)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    [junit] mainpackage.base.view.translator.exception.TranslationException: Cannot load translation for locale en_US and MIB version #R_LR14_01_L#V_45.4.3; will use locale en_US and no MIB version.
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.view.translator.Translator.createTranslation(Translator.java:163)
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.view.translator.Translator.<init>(Translator.java:31)
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.view.translator.TranslatorFactory.getTranslator(TranslatorFactory.java:116)
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.manager.BsManager.setMibVersion(BsManager.java:1469)
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.action.ConnectAction.action(ConnectAction.java:314)
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.action.AbstractAction.run(AbstractAction.java:164)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    [junit] java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name mainpackage.rlr14_01.V_45_4_3.view.translation.Translation, locale en_US
    [junit]     at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
    [junit]     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
    [junit]     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:795)
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.view.translator.Translator.createTranslation(Translator.java:125)
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.view.translator.Translator.<init>(Translator.java:31)
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.view.translator.TranslatorFactory.getTranslator(TranslatorFactory.java:120)
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.manager.BsManager.setMibVersion(BsManager.java:1469)
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.action.ConnectAction.action(ConnectAction.java:314)
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.action.AbstractAction.run(AbstractAction.java:164)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    [junit] Exception in thread "ConnectAction" java.lang.NullPointerException
    [junit]     at mainpackage.base.action.AbstractAction.run(AbstractAction.java:174)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Build was aborted
```

Comment: Please give us a little bit more context. Which target do you run and which is the target with the error? Does the error only appear while running in Jenkins or is it reproducible running Ant at the command line? And can you post the full stack trace? "From Eclipse everything is working fine" What does it mean exactly? Do you run an Ant task in Eclipse?

Comment: I have edited the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. It is just a path problem.

I had this problem yesterday, using

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle(propertyFileName, locale)
```

my property files where in the same package.
Which command you are using to read the property file?

I resolved it by moving the property file to the source folder.

So if you have a package com.example.common placed in sourcefolder named "src" you have on your filesystem .../src/com/example/common.

1. In this example you should try to move the propery files into the "src" folder.
2. If you stil have the error:

Are you copying the property files with your ant script?
I can't find it in your script.

Maybe you need something like:

```
<copy todir="${basedir}/yourDestinationPath">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/src" includes="*.properties"/>
</copy>
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it doesn't work. I manually copied the .properties file to the src folder and nothing changed.

Comment: Property files here: mainpackage.rlr14_01.V_45_4_3.view.translation.Translation?

Look into your junit tests, find where the command getBundle(...) is used.